# Rails: call a parent model 's attribute in View?

Tags: view, model, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations

here i have 2 simple model with one-many relation:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :Name
  has_many :items

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :Category_id, :Name, :Price, :Description
  belongs_to :category
```

and I've a View to show info about Item like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="field" style="width: 175px;"><b>Name:</b></td>
    <td><%= @item.Name %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="field"><b>Price:</b></td>
    <td><%= @item.Price%></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="field"><b>Category: </b></td>
    <td><%= Category.find(@item.Category_id).Name %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="field"><b>Description: </b></td>
    <td><%= @item.Description %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It's work right. But here I've a question: Is there's another ways to call class `Category` 's attribute. Something like `@item.category.Name` which I try but didn't work ( `undefined method "Name" for nil:NilClass`)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have your attributes in camel case? Downcase them and change this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="field"><b>Category: </b></td>
    <td><%= Category.find(@item.Category_id).Name %></td>
  </tr>
```

to this:

```
<tr>
  <td class="field"><b>Category: </b></td>
  <td><%= item.category.name %></td>
</tr>
```

It should work.

Comment: still not work, have error like I mentioned above `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a nil check would help, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208523/undefined-method-for-nilnilclass-on-an-association-view).

```
<tr>
  <td class="field"><b>Category: </b></td>
  <td><%= @item.category.name unless @item.category.nil? %></td>
</tr>
```